# Illegal Character in Query at Index 40 : when passing double quotes in the header value

Tags: urlencode, mulesoft, mule4

I have the following URL placed in a property file 
mws.add=#['http://kappt.pc.net/LWS/POB/MS.asmx?RK=' ++ vars.RK]

I am passing RK as an header when calling the API ad it is defined as string type in RAML.

when I am passing RK= "abcd" in Postman header, I am getting an error as 
Root Exception stack trace:
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 40 : http://kappt.pc.net/LWS/POB/MS.asmx?RK="abcd"

How can I encode this URL in property file?

Comment: did you tried removing `++` ?

Comment: How are you using the property `mws.add` in the Mule application? Show the snippet and also add the full error.